# Passing a prop to a child created after component mounts

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have a component that is a container for a `<canvas>`. I have other components that take a canvas context as a prop and can be used to manipulate it in various ways; like so:

```
class App extends React.Component {
  ctx: CanvasRenderingContext2D;
  canvas: HTMLCanvasElement;

  componentDidMount() {
    this.ctx = this.canvas.getContext('2d') as CanvasRenderingContext2D;
    this.forceUpdate();
  }

  render() {
    const circle = this.ctx ? <Circle ctx={this.ctx} /> : '';
    return (
      <canvas ref={ref => (this.canvas = ref as HTMLCanvasElement)}>
        {circle}
      </canvas>
    );
  }
}

const Circle = ({ ctx }: { ctx: CanvasRenderingContext2D }) => {
  ctx.arc(10, 10, 10, 0, 6);
  ctx.stroke();
  return null;
};
```

This works as expected and draws a circle, but I'm not sure that this is the best way to go about it. I have a couple of issues:

- I'm not sure about the `forceUpdate` call.
- If I don't do the conditional check on `ctx`, it will be undefined when Circle first renders.

I was originally using `componentWillMount`, but the problem is that the ref is not set so `this.canvas` is undefined.

Is there a proper way to pass props to child components that depend on refs in the parent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think one way to do that would be as below:

```
class App extends React.Component {
  ctx: CanvasRenderingContext2D;
  canvas: HTMLCanvasElement;

  constructor(props){
     super(props);
     this.state={ ctx:null }
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.setState({ctx:this.canvas.getContext('2d') as CanvasRenderingContext2D})
  }

  render() {
    const circle = this.state.ctx? <Circle ctx={this.state.ctx} /> : '';
    return (
      <canvas ref={ref => (this.canvas = ref as HTMLCanvasElement)}>
        {circle}
      </canvas>
    );
  }
}
```